# Tool to annotate html files (preferably within web browser)

Tags: nlp, annotation

I want to annotate web pages to tag words as certain classes. I have tried [brat](http://brat.nlplab.org) but this only works with .txt files. I think a chrome/firefox extension would be best since the browser could easily render the html and I could annotate the text and than save the html than.

Is anyone aware of a tool to do this already?

Comment: NER? Not that it's relevant to the question, you can [edit] it out as well.

Comment: I have no experience with these but [Google "browser postit"](https://www.google.com/search?q=browser+postit)